# How to prove that every bijective rational function is a linear fractional transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove that every bijective rational function (over the field of complex numbers) is a linear fractional transformation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say $f(x)/g(x)=t$ for a given $t$ then consider the polynomial $h(x)=f(x)-tg(x)$. Over the complex numbers $h$ will more than one root if $f, g$ are not of degree 1. So the only bijections are the linear fractional transformations.

Comment: I love this answer! It is flawless.

Comment: How do you handle the case where $t$ is a root with multiplicity $>1$, please?

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Not any $t$ does the job. This is explained in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389265/prove-that-injective-rational-function-on-complex-numbers-are-mobius-transformat?noredirect=1&lq=1).