# Bijective rational function over complex numbers must be linear fractional transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a rational bijective function. So, $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ where $p,q$ are polynomials and $q(z)$ is not identically zero. I know that over $\mathbb{C}$, $p$ and $q$ factor completely into their linear roots. Without loss of generality, let $p$ and $q$ have distinct roots, for otherwise they would just cancel in $f$.

I know $p$ can't have distinct roots, because if it did, then $f$ wouldn't be injective. Since $f$ is injective, $(1/f)$ is injective, so by the same argument, $q$ can't have distinct roots.

What I don't understand is why $p$ or $q$ can't have repeated roots. For example, what if $p(z) = (z -\alpha)^3$? I know that $p$ having repeated roots means that $p$ isn't injective, but does this necessarily violate the injectivity of f? How do I show that $f$ must be a linear fractional transformation?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199137/how-to-prove-that-every-bijective-rational-function-is-a-linear-fractional-trans?rq=1